Setting up documentation html site using Sphinx on GitHub
I am trying to publish my Sphinx documentation on GitHub. I keep getting 404 error once deployed (no errors in GitHub actions flagged).
The html works fine when built locally and displayed in browser.
This is my test repo: https://github.com/JKucera-NCC/TestSphinx/deployments
I tried following documentation: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/tutorial/deploying.html#id5 (and also it's older version)
I tried following amended versions of it provided in solutions to similar issues, eg: How to self-host Read the Docs using GitHub Pages
I tried using dedicated branch gh-pages for the deployment.
I tried deploying on public personal repo, and on public organization repo.
I played with the deployment branch and location in the setting/pages.
Once I solve other specific issues, I always end up with the same error page:

I would appreciate any ideas on what to try next.
EDIT:
The testing repository from above is deleted. For now I have given up on resolving this issue properly. I generate the Sphinx docs manual offline, and then push finalized docs into dedicated branch (no longer trying to use action to auto generate docs on push).

Did you follow all the instructions at https://pages.github.com/ ? Start with something simple. Just publish one simple index.html. Show us your repository settings related to Pages.

@phd this repository is the simple test repository, it only contains the Sphinx docs folder. The intended parent repository is https://github.com/National-Composites-Centre/LayupDefinition , but I wanted to show the simplest option, not to get the answers affected by bunch of things I already solved.
